# Text Adventure Game: How to define rooms outside of program?

Tags: python, adventure

I have gone through many of these threads with rooms but it still has not answered my question.

I want to define 5 rooms with items each inside it without the program being recursive. At the rate I am going it will take forever. The code is unfinished but you will see what I mean.

```
print("""
You enter the simulation. You look forward around you and examine the walls around the maze you are about to step foot into

Will you go forward? (Yes/No)
""")

ans1 = input("> ")

if ans1 in answer_yes:
    print("You walk forward and enter the maze. You run into a room with 3 doors. Will you choose (Door 1/Door 2/Door 3)\n")

    ans2 = input("> ")

    if ans2 in answer_door3:
        print("This door seems to lead down into a pitch black, empty hall. Would you like to proceed? (Yes/No)")

        ans3 = input("> ")

        if ans3 in answer_yes:
            print("The hall does not seem to stop. You might want to turn around.")

elif ans1 in answer_no:
    print("You can wait here forever then. They will never let you out! Will you go? (Yes/No)")

    ans3= input("> ")

else:
    print("Wrong input, please try again.")
```

I want to make it so I start in a certain room and that room has 4 doors which all lead to a certain area and have these rooms connect if the user follows the "correct" path.

I started by defining the rooms.

`rooms = {'Auditorium', 'Kitchen', 'Bedroom 1', 'Bedroom 2', 'Computing Room'}`

Have 0 clue what to do from here.

Comment: You'll want to learn about [finite-state machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), where rooms are states and the ability to move from one room to another is the transition function fo the state machine.